# Show contents of media query to ie8

Tags: css, responsive-design

There's a fairly old [article on smashing magazine](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/08/10/techniques-for-gracefully-degrading-media-queries/) (technique 3) that says that if you start a media query like this:

`@media screen, all and (min-width: 300px)`

then browsers that understand media queries will understand the whole media query where as older ie will ignore everything after "all and". So in theory older ie still sees everything inside the query. This is amazingly true for ie6 and ie7 but unfortunately ie8 ignores all the rules inside the query.

It's unfortunate because if we could get

We can do something similar using [Jeremy Keiths example](http://adactio.com/journal/4494/) which involves moving the layout stuff into a separate style sheet and using conditional comments to serve this to older IE.

The problem with this approach is that that my css modules are split between separate style sheets. This goes against principles in OOCSS and SMACSS (which are really useful!)

There's a [JS Fiddle where someone has tried to crack it](http://jsfiddle.net/boblet/59e99/) but wondering if anyone has any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: If you're open to using CSS Preprocessors, Sass can do this quite easily:  http://jakearchibald.github.com/sass-ie/

Comment: Thanks but please see my last comment regarding OOCSS - its the same principle of splitting out CSS modules into extra style sheets. When updating an old website its much easier to see all the breakpoints in the same place without having to open up more sass files.

Comment: Except that it's not?  It generates 2 different stylesheets:  a "responsive" one that you hide from IE<8 and one you feed to IE<8 via conditional comments that has no media queries in it and only styles it would actually see if it understood media queries properly.  The Sass files themselves are organized however you please.

Comment: My mistake - Apologies, I use .less and the syntax confused me! I need to re-read this a few times to get it to sink but wanted to post back to thank you for think link.

Answer (score 0):

Credit to @cimmanon for the comment which led me to a solution.

Using .less I can have

global.less - This has all my CSS in there including all my breakpoints. The breakpoints are set as less variables.
compiled.less - This imports global.less and compiles to a css file
Compiled-belowie8 - This imports global.less and compiles to a css file BUT I've changed the widest layout's media query variable to "none" so that in this one there is no media query.

Then, in the  I've used conditional comments to serve compiled.css to all browsers except